# How do I configure my babel/preset-env in my package.json file?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I'm trying to learn machine learning with JavaScript on my own but I'm having trouble even setting up my package.json file. I've Googled everywhere and tried different things but I keep on getting the following error

```
$ browserify src/index.js --node -o dist/index.js -t [ babelify --presets [ env ] ]
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null while parsing file: C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\MLinJSBook\Ch1-Ex1\src\greeting.js
```

And here's my 
Here's my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "Ch1-Ex1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build-web": "browserify src/index.js -o dist/index.js -t [ babelify --presets [ env ] ]",
    "build-cli": "browserify src/index.js --node -o dist/index.js -t [ babelify --presets [ env ] ]",
    "start": "yarn build-cli && node dist/index.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "browserify": "^16.2.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.0"
  }
}
```

And my code greetingg.js

```
const greeting = name => 'Hello, ' + name + '!';
export default greeting;
```

index.js

```
import greeting from './greeting';
console.log(greeting(process.argv[2] || 'world'));
```

I think I'm not configuring my babel/preset-env correctly but I everything I've tried is not working. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Babel 7 you have to update your command to use `"@babel/preset-env"` instead of `env` in presets.

```
$ browserify src/index.js --node -o dist/index.js -t [ babelify --presets ["@babel/preset-env" ] ]
```

Source: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/env/